# Indexing JSON in GeoMesa

Tags: geomesa

Assume I want to perist JSON files in GeoMesa (on Accumulo). These JSON files have geometries and time. Can I use a XZ3 index? If yes then how?

NB: By JSON I am not refering to GeoJSON.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a GeoMesa converter (a configuration file) to extract the values you want out of your JSON and into a GeoTools SimpleFeature, and ingest those into GeoMesa. Download the Accumulo distribution from [github](https://github.com/locationtech/geomesa/releases/tag/geomesa_2.11-1.3.4) and look at the example under `examples/ingest/json/`.
Full documentation for converters is available [here](http://www.geomesa.org/documentation/user/convert/index.html).

You also have the option of storing JSON strings as attributes, and querying them using JSON-Path. There is more information on that [here](http://www.geomesa.org/documentation/user/geojson.html#json-attributes).

The indices created for your data will depend on the attributes present. If you have a non-point geometry and a date defined, then you will automatically build an XZ3 index. More information on indices is available [here](http://www.geomesa.org/documentation/user/datastores/index_overview.html) and [here](http://www.geomesa.org/documentation/user/datastores/index_basics.html)

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer. I will check the links. Fast question: JSON string as attribute also uses an index (only for GeoJSON I have seen index)? I haven't seen any reference to create to give a JSONPath where to create the index. Populating a SimpleFeature from a JSON can be done manually and adding an index to SimpleFeature can also be done (this is clear).

Comment: The JSON string attribute itself can't be indexed. If you want to index a particular JSONPath, you can extract it into a separate attribute in the converter, and index that attribute.